# Using table names in SQL queries if field names are unique?

Tags: mysql, sql

Do table name prefixes need to be specified in a MySQL query if all column names are unique? Does it affect performance if not using them? Is it the same for SQL in general? For example:

**Without prefixes**

```
SELECT
id_events, title_events, name_venues, name_cities 
FROM 
(events 
  LEFT JOIN venues ON idvenues_event = id_venues) 
    LEFT JOIN cities ON idcities_events = id_cities
```

**With prefixes**

```
SELECT
e.id_events, e.title_events, v.name_venues, c.name_cities 
FROM 
(events AS e
  LEFT JOIN venues As v ON e.idvenues_event = v.id_venues) 
    LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON e.idcities_events = c.id_cities
```

Comment: this is http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f6a70/3  why i always use aliases or table names in every query because it can cause problems with selecting data or even corrupt update data.

Comment: Good point. It is clearly a good practice but I just wanted to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1. Do table name prefixes need to be specified in a MySQL query if all column names are unique?***

*No need to. But for better readability table name or a alias is given to column name so it can be easily understand*

**SQL Aliases**

- SQL aliases are used to give a table, or a column in a table, `a temporary name`.
- Aliases are often used to make column names `more readable`.
- An alias only `exists for the duration of the query`.

***2. Does it affect performance?***

*No, performance on depends on the load which you gave on a query*

A view, being just a query persisted in the database, `should not theoretically have any performance hit`. Same is true for column or table aliases. The performance hit, if any, will be barely noticeable once the execution plan is compiled and cached by the database engine. So, there is no performance justification not to use column aliases based on views.

***3. Is it the same for SQL in general?***

*Yes.*